# How to copy java GAE local_db.bin from one computer to the other?

Tags: java, google-app-engine, gwt, google-cloud-datastore

I am developing a web application with a friend. He started the project and he has the correct local datastore for testing. I need to copy this datastore to my local application, but don't know how. I already tried to copy his `local_db.bin` and `datastore-indexes-auto.xml` to my `appengine-generated` folder, but it didn't work.

Is there a way to accomplish that?

Comment: What do you mean by "it did not work"? I do it all the time.

Comment: Really? This is strange. When I use my version of `local_db.bin` I get to the screen I need, but when I use my friends version I don't go anywhere. It's like the application is loading, but it is not (never ends). (Edit) Oh, I forgot but the `_ah/admin` part doesn't show any entities either using my friends file.

Answer (score 0):

The problem you describe usually happens when the new version of the app is not compatible with the local_db.bin file, or when you upgrade to the new App Engine SDK.

The best solution is to use Mercurial or Git, and include local_db.bin file in the repository. Then you can check in all changes, and it will keep local_db.bin in sync with code changes. Also make sure that all members of the team use the same SDK.

Comment: Maybe you're right. Just discovered we are using different versions of the gwt skd (mine is 2.5 and his is 2.4). The appengine sdk version, though, is the same. I don't know if it metters, but we use slightly different jdk versions (mine is jdk1.6.0_35 and his is jdk1.6.0_31). I'll try to use his gwt sdk and see if the `local_db.bin` works. Thanks!

Comment: Just tried with the other version of gwt and yet the local datastore is empty. I guess Java version wouldn't cause this kind of problem (I have even ran this project with Java 7 before without trouble). Another suggestion?

Comment: local_db.bin is a serialized Java object. According to Ikai Lan from Google, "When we try to read in the object from the file and fail to deserialize, we just start with an empty datastore." This means that if App Engine SDK is the same, there are some differences in your code.

Comment: By the way, verify that you have actually replaced local_db.bin file - check its size before you run your app.

Comment: Our code is the same (we use Git, but without sharing the local_db.bin until today =) ). And I verified the files too (mine was several times smaller than my friends'). That comment from Ikai Lan is exactly what happens.